Route system sounds to audio interface with PipeWire and JACK as source
I'm a musician and software developer and I'm looking to switch to linux my recording stack. I use Linux for work and Windows for music production/recording and I would love to get rid of Windows and use just Linux full time. I'm currently using Ubuntu 24, which comes natively with Pipewire. I looked up how to use it and understood that Pipewire emulates JACK and PulseAudio APIs, so I don't need to install either JACK or Pulse.
I'm using Scarlett solo 2i2 audio interface with Reaper as DAW.
I want to connect Reaper output AND chrome output (or other software sources) to the Scarlett.
Reaper has only support for ALSA and JACK (and Pulse).
When I connect qjackctl to the (emulated?) JACK server, the Scarlett sink disappears from qpwgraphctl and I lost connection between chrome and the audio interface. Instead, the connection between Reaper and Scarlett is ok.
qjackctl with JACK connected and Reaper
qpwgraphctl with JACK connected and Reaper
When I disconnect qjackctl the Scarlett sink and sources re-appear in qpwgraphctl but I can't connect Reaper because it works only with JACK.
qpwgraphctl with JACK disconnected
Reaper audio options
I'm getting into Linux audio stacks now, so if I've said anything stupid, correct me!

Ok, I found a workaround, somehow it seems wrong but it works. I start Reaper with command
pw-jack reaper

correct audio routing

ok, everything fine but I faced some latency issues. PIPEWIRE_LATENCY="128/48000" pw-jack reaper fix the problem

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
